# Как освободиться из тюрьмы

Tags: алгоритм

Во дворе тюрьмы поле 16х16. На некоторых из клеток лежат камни, на некоторых нет. Тюремщик выводит первого заключенного и указывает на случайную клетку, после чего заключенный может изменить состояние одной любой клетки - убрать или добавить камень (или же ничего не менять). После чего заключенного уводят и приводят другого, который должен угадать клетку, на которую указал тюремщик первому (в этом случае их освобождают иначе им грозит казнь).

Заключенные могут оговорить стратегию заранее, но после начала "игры" они не "общаются" ни каким образом. Состояние поля оба заключенных не видят до начала "игры".

Как выиграть?

Comment: Да здравствует самый справедливый суд в мире!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом:

1. Пронумеровываем все камни в соответствии с их позицией. Т.е., например, камень в клетке 0x0 будет иметь позицию 0, а камень в клетке 16x16 позицию 255
2. Для всех позиций камней на поле применяем XOR (исключающее ИЛИ) и получаем на выходе некоторое произвольное число от 0 до 255.
3. Если число из п.2 совпадает с позицией на которую указал тюремщик, то переходим к п.5
4. Иначе еще раз применяем XOR для полученного в п.2 числа и позиции на которую указал тюремщик. Результирующее число будет позицией той клетки в которой мы и будем менять состояние:

   - Если в клетке уже лежит камень, то убираем его.
   - Иначе добавляем камень.
5. Теперь когда придет второй заключенный, то проделав п.1 и п.2 он однозначно получит позицию клетки на которую указал тюремщик.

Comment: Поясните п.2. Первый аргумент операции XOR - N-ная позиция камня от 0 до 255, а второй аргумент ?

Comment: @Mikola, смотрите, к примеру, если у нас лежат камни в позициях 1, 100 и 237, то результатом п.2 для первого заключеного будет выражение: 

    1 XOR 100 XOR 237 = 136

Если тюремщик укажет на позицию `42`, то положив камень в позицию: `136 XOR 42 = 162`, второй тюремщик выполнив п.2 получит

    1 XOR 100 XOR 237 XOR 162 = 42

Т.е. искомую позицию.

Comment: По-моему, идеально.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov , спасибо, теперь понятно.

Comment: А ещё можно использовать суммирование по модулю количества полей. Будет работать и в случае произвольного количества полей (не степень 2).

Comment: @sercxjo, XOR - это и есть [суммирование по модулю](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_2).

Про степень 2 не понял. Этот алгоритм будет работать для произвольного числа полей. Или я не понял что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Не по модулю 2 а по модулю количества клеток. Пусть есть 100 клеток, три камня в клетках 1, 23, 95. Суммируем позиции камней по модулю 100:

    (1 + 23 + 95) mod 100 = 19

Из адреса указанного поля (42) надо вычесть эту сумму по модулю 100:

    (42 - 19) mod 100 = 23

Итак первый заключённый кладёт камень в клетку 23.

второй суммирует:

    (1 + 23 + 23 + 95) mod 100 = 42

(В условиях задачи не сказано, что нельзя класть  второй камень в ту же клетку)

Comment: > после чего заключенный может **изменить состояние** одной любой клетки

По моему, в задаче явно дается понять, что клетка может быть только в двух состояниях. В остальном понял, спасибо.

Comment: 2 @Ilya Pirogov: у вас алгоритм верный но обьяснение как-то запутанно. мне кажется так будет доступнее:  

`за состояние каждого поля отвечает 1 конкретный бит. у нас всего 256 позиций. т.е. 8 байт. для того чтоб узнать изначальное расположение полей достаточно запомнить число (легче всего если преобразовать его в 10ричную систему). для того чтоб найти изменившееся поле достаточно сделать XOR текущего состояния с исходным`

Comment: @jmu, ничего вы не поняли. Мы не ищем изменившееся поле, мы ищем клетку указанную тюремщиком. Информация, которая нам нужна - это номер клетки, её адрес. Эта информация - число от 0 до 255 - умещается в **одном** байте. Второй заключённый не может узнать как выглядело поле до того как первый изменил там состояние одной клетки ни какую клетку он изменил, но может посчитать контрольную сумму адресов тех камней которые он видит с помощью побитного xor. Он получит число от 0 до 255. Первый заключённый должен сделать так, чтобы у второго получился адрес указанной клетки.

Comment: да, затупил чуток

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, как-то у вас много текста)

    x - позиции исходных камней
    y - позиции получившихся камней    
    xor() - xor элементов массива
    e - позиция изменяемой ячейки
    f - позиция указанной ячейки
    
    xor(y) = xor(xor(x), e) = f
    e = xor(xor(x), f)
    f = xor(y)

Comment: @timka_s, нигде в условиях задачи не указано, что необходимо вывести *формулу* или описать *алгоритм* одним предложением, поэтому я расписал его так, как его, на мой взгляд, проще воспринимать.

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю такой алгоритм (вероятность выигрыша считайте сами).

Первый игрок должен сделать, чтобы количество камней на горизонтали и вертикали, проходящих через указанную клеку было нечётно.

Если оба числа чётные - надо изменить состояние указанной клетки.

Если одно из чисел нечётно, например для горизонтали - надо изменить состояние другой клетки на этой линии, при этом желательно выбрать клетку, у которой сумма по вертикали нечётная.

Если оба числа указанной клетки нечётные - надо найти две другии вертикали и горизонтали с нечётным числом камней и изменить состояние клетки на их пересечении, если такой клетки нет - ничего не делать.

Второй игрок должен найти горизонталь и вертикаль с нечётным количеством камней. Конечно он может ошибиться, первый игрок только уменьшает вероятность этой ошибки.

Модификация: критерий чётность/нечётность выбирается для вертикали и горизонтали отдельно из того каких линий меньше. Т.е. если меньше чётных - берём критерием чётность и т.п. Первый игрок уменьшает количество этих линий на 1.

Comment: Самая большая проблема - если кол-во клеток на пересечении линий с нечётным кол-вом камней больше 3-х.

Comment: @Spectre, не понятно, объясните подробнее

Comment: А, понял, вы имеете в виду что остаются клетки, которые могут быть ошибочно выбраны вторым игроком. Да, если таких клеток 2 - можно одним камнем их обезвредить, а если больше, проблема останется.

Comment: Да, именно.